Printing label with MAUI
I have to develop an application which has the following requirements:

run on Azure
can view on Windows and Android (later maybe other platforms must be supported)
can print labels through installed printers on the client (Zebra and Datamax printers)
support both local (USB Bluetooth) and network printers
printing with raw commands

I started with Blazor Server App but the weak point was the printing. I can't see the printers installed on the client. Browser's printing window is not an option for me. I have to select one of the installed printer and send raw ZPL, DPL, etc. commands silently.
After this I found the MAUI technology. Is it possible to solve this printing issue with MAUI and keep cross platform support?
I think on Android extra application is  mandatory for installing printers but I think it is OK. Or am I wrong?
Installing client helper application for printing is not a solution.
